# Handle raise ActiveStorage::InvariableError after Deleting a file that uploaded with active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

Hello i uploaded an image with active storage specificly an avatar for my model users,  but after of upload this image, i delete this of the folder that contained the file. then, i have one attachment that exists without file.

i am checking user.avatar.blob (the user with the deleted file), and then this return null (with the console), i am try to handle this inside of a view but dont works, any advice for handle this exception?

```
 <% unless !!user.avatar.blob.nil? || user.avatar.attached? %>

#this a simple avatar api that show for default
# an image when dont exist attachement or the file dont works or dont exist

      <%= image_tag "https://avatars.dicebear.com/4.5/api/#{user.gender}/#{user.username}.svg?mood[]=happy&mood[]=happy", :size => "100x100" %>

    <% else %>

      <%= image_tag user.avatar.variant(
      resize_to_limit: [100, 100]
      )%>


    <% end %>
```

Comment: is `nill?` with double `l` a typo? what's `user.avatar.blob` at that point in the code? you can put a `byebug` statement before that and inspect the values

Comment: sorry i wrong with nil, but the same way dont works.